# Let A and B be two sets of points in the plane - determine whether A and B can be separated by a disk

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Let A and B be two sets of points in the plane, each consisting of n points.
I am trying to find a efficient way to determine whether A and B can be separated by a disk - does there exist a disk D such that all the points of A lie inside D, and all the points of B lie out side it D?

There is also a hint:
Use lifting to three dimensions.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embed the points as (x, y) ↦ (x, y, x² + y²) and test whether there is a separating hyperplane. This works because

- If we have parameters (a, b, c) such that a x + b y + x² + y² < c if (x, y) ∈ A and > c if (x, y) ∈ B, then the comparison is equivalent to (x − (−a/2))² + (y − (−b/2))² ? c + (−a/2)² + (−b/2)², which is equivalent to a separating circle with center (−a/2, −b/2) and radius √(c + (−a/2)² + (−b/2)²);
- Conversely, we can do the algebra to go from a separating circle to a separating hyperplane.

Comment: @firev2 Probably would have taken me longer, but embedding higher-order terms in extra dimensions comes up in a couple different branches of mathematics.